# Is a Banach space with a predual of arbitrary order necessarily reflexive?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras

Let $X$ be a Banach space, by a predual of order $n$ ($n$ is a positive integer), I mean a Banach space $X_{n}$, such that the $n$-th dual $X_n^{(n)}$ of $X_n$ is isometrically isomorphic to $X$. My question is, suppose $X_n$ exists for any $n \ge 1$, does it follow that $X$ itself must be reflexive?

I also have a follow-up question depending on the answer to the above question. If positive, then does the same still hold for (complete) locally convex spaces where we always equip the dual space with the strong topology? If negative, i.e. there does exist a non-reflexive Banach space $X$ admiting a predual of order $n$ for all $n \ge 1$, then is there a $W^*$-algebra $M$ whose underlying Banach space has the same property?

Comment: Do you mean to ask about "preduals" or "bi-preduals"? Most reflexive Banach spaces aren't isomorphic to their duals... What about the James space?

Comment: @MatthewDaws it doesn't have to be isomorphic to its dual, reflexive Banach space has its dual as its odd order predual and itself as its even order predual.

Comment: @MatthewDaws You are right about James space being an example of non-reflexive Banach space having a predual of arbitrary order. Now the question remains whether a $W^*$-algebra can have preduals of arbitrary order.

Comment: The cardinality $\gamma(M)$ of a maximal family of mutually orthogonal nonzero projections in $M$ is an invariant of a von Neumann algebra $M$ (if I remember correctly). It satisfies $\gamma(M^{\ast\ast})\geq 2^{2^{\gamma(M)}}$. Hence there is no sequence $M_n$ with $M_n^{\ast\ast}\cong M_{n-1}$, because it violates well-orderedness of cardinalities. However, this isn't enough to exclude the possibility of predual of arbitrary order, because the second predual isn't unique. Perhaps, still we can do by considering $\gamma_n(M)=\sup\{ \gamma(M_n) : M_n^{\ast\ast\cdots\ast\ast}\cong M\}$.

Comment: Correction: Not "maximal family", but "maximal cardinality", or just "any family of mutually orthogonal nonzero $\sigma$-finite projections" (assuming that $M$ is not finite-dimensional). Any von Neumann algebra $M$ is isomorphic to $\prod_i N_i\otimes B(\ell_2(J_i))$ with $N_i$ $\sigma$-finite, which gives $\gamma(M)=\sum_i \aleph_0\cdot|J_i|$.

Comment: Perhaps it is helpful to note that part of [Godefroy, Theorem 3](http://www.numdam.org/item/SC_1976-1977__16__A8_0.pdf) says that a Banach space $E$ is isometrically isomorphic to a dual of another Banach space if and only if there is a subspace $V$ in the dual $E^*$ such that (a) $E^{**}=i(E) \oplus V^\perp$  where $i: E \to E^{**}$ is the canonical embedding; (b) the $\sigma(E^*, E)$-closure in $E^*$ of the closed unit ball of $V$ is exactly the closed unit ball of $E^*$.